# Hide "Open in app" banner while using Universal links

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I'm using Universal links and everything is working perfectly but I can't seem to hide the **Open in app** banner which shows in the safari. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Have the same issue on our website homepage, finally removed homepage link form universal links in the Apple App Site Association file.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing you can do about that really, it's a feature of Universal Links and gets injected automatically by Safari.

Usually, they're hidden until you overscroll the content.

Comment: I think @Oleksiy has suggested a possible answer below, which I'm gonna give a try later today and post the results here.

Comment: @AkshitZaveri can you share your exp on this & what's your approach

Answer (score 1):

What goal you are trying to achieve by using Universal Links?
Usually developers are using Universal Links if they want for all/part of the website to be viewable in the App. From this point of view, screenshot you posted is a failure, because Universal Links failed to engage. Possible reasons can be if navigation to the Universal Links domains happened as redirect.

If there are specific pages on your website that you don't want become viewable in the App, you can use exclusions list in associated domain file. Check out this example http://amazon.com/apple-app-site-association . In this case navigating to the "*/ref=nodl_*" will not open the Amazon  and will not show the banner you are mentioning.

Comment: So, it's all about the path that we put in the app-site-association file then?

Comment: If you don't want for some path to be handled in App, then you exclude the path.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can hide the smart banner by edit your apple-app-association file in the root directory of your website. You can control the banner on the pages you want to show.

you cannot hide the banner while using the universal links at the same time.
You can only hide the banner where you do not want the universal links to work by restricting the paths in apple-app-association file.

If you want to hide the banner form all the pages just add 
"paths":["NOT /*"] in details object in this case universal links will not work.

Comment: by this you turn off all universal links, not only smart banner in safari..

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking how to hide the banner while still using universal links.