# How to interceptor iOS universal links in an App

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I work about universal links iOS recently. But I found out that in some App, my universal links can't open my App 100%. So, I want to know how to prevent a universal links to open a third part App in my App. Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code/things you have tried as of now.

Comment: Thers's no code. I just wonna to prevent a universal link invoke. I want to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Links require explicit user interaction to engage. If navigation to Universal Links happens as a result of Java Script redirect, or server redirect or by navigation from another App, then Universal Links will not engage and user will stay in browser/webview. Also it is possible for the user to disable Universal Links for specific domain on specific device.

Alternatively, if you want to blacklist some pages of the website to be opened in the App you can edit AASA file to exclude these pages. See also this answer [Hide "Open in app" banner while using Universal links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284440/hide-open-in-app-banner-while-using-universal-links/45293638#45293638)

Does this answers your question?

Comment: Sorry, editing AASA file can justify my App opened in other App. What I want if to prevent other App opened in my App. I test the Universal link in a H5 with a <a href="XXX"></a>. It does do a user interaction, not a redirect, so I'm confused that how it is implemented.

Comment: Probably would be nice if you can describe what you trying to do and what dopes not working. When you saying App do you mean s native iOS App or something different?